# bitbucket asking for password connecting to GIT: how to remove

Tags: bitbucket

So I own a bitbucket and invited a dev with write permissions to add to the bitbucket with code. There are no piplines. This was a year ago before covid. Now that dev is not reachable so we have hired another. They tried to connect to the bitbucket's GIT but are prompted by the password for his?? - we think - email address?
[image]
I dont understand how this came to be given that he was not an admin and we have always owned the bitbucket. How do we remove this email address and reset to ours?

Answer (score 1):

What you see is not an email address -- rather, it is a Bitbucket Cloud username that is part of a repository URL like `https://someusername@bitbucket.org/someteam/some-git-project.git`.

Your new dev is probably using a local repo that was originally cloned (`git clone ...`) by your old dev using that person's credentials in the URL.

**If you would like to use the existing copy of the repository**, run `git remote -v` to list the configured remotes for the repository. These are other copies of the repo that git knows how to push to & pull from (such as `origin`, which is probably Bitbucket Cloud).

If you see that the username is part of the URL for a remote, then you will need to [adjust the remote's URL using `git remote set-url ....`](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/managing-remote-repositories). Specify the new dev's username, and assuming they have permissions, the next `git fetch`, etc. should work fine.

**If you are OK with a new copy of the repository**, the new dev can clone the repository in a new location using [the standard process](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/clone-a-repository/). Then you can delete the old repo from the machine. Any branches & commits that were never pushed to a/the remote (like Bitbucket Cloud, GitHub, etc.) would be lost.

Comment: @user15081222 Did this answer your question? If so, please mark it so, or if not, please add additional details either in the question or as a comment to the answer.